# Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSManagedObjectContext' using CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

i'm trying to do something with CoreData but got confused, i declared persistentContainer, but when i try get the viewContext, it went wrong, some help would be great!

```
let container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let width = textView.frame.size.width
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: .infinity)
    let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)
    let tenTextLines = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).lineHeight * 10

    if textView == textTextView {
        if let text = textTextView.text {
            container?.viewContext { context in      //err:Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSManagedObjectContext'
                _ = try? Entry.findOrCreatEntry(matching: text, in: context)
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant

```
if textView == textTextView {
    if let text = textTextView.text, let context = container?.viewContext {
       _ = try? Entry.findOrCreatEntry(matching: text, in: context)
    }
...
```

Comment: your code worked. but i still don't understand why mine doesn't, could you explained it for me? I'm new to this, thanks for your patience！

Comment: `NSPersistentContainer.viewContext` is a property (getter), but notation `.viewContext { }` is as it would be function `viewContext(_ : () -> Void)`, so error is shown.

Comment: You really helped me a lot! Thank you so much!